# Multiseat login issue

Tags: multiseat

I have created a multi seat Ubuntu 16.04 and separated the devices to two seats.

I was able to login to the first seat i.e., seat0 without any issues do the work in it.

While coming to second seat i.e., seat1 i am not able to login and it is showing as Retry "Failed to authenticate" for every user. but with the same user i am able to login in seat0.

Please help us or guide resolve the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a bug in the newer version of lightdm (1.18.2). Try to downgrade to the previous version using:

```
sudo apt install lightdm=1.18.1*
echo "lightdm hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Obs: The last line puts lightdm on hold to avoid upgrades to the 1.18.2 version. Once the newer version is fixed you want to re-allow the upgrade by using

```
echo "lightdm install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Maybe the related bug is this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1599478